# Как повторно вызывать окно любое количество раз в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется панель (окно) выбора детали для добавления:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая кнопка имеет пару в словаре, чтобы в единственном обработчике клика вызывать нужное окно по ключу-кнопке:

```
private Dictionary<CustomButton, Window> detailsWindowsPairs = new();

 private void AddPairs()
    {
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(CapacitorAddButton, new CapasitorsAddPanel());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(CommProductAddButton, new CommProductsAddPanel());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(DiodeAddButton, new DiodesAddPanel());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(MicrocircuitAddButton, new MicrocircuitsAddPanel());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(ResistorAddButton, new ResistorsAddPanel());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(InductanceAddButton, new InductanceAddWindow());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(ThyristorAddButton, new ThyristorAddWindow());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(TransistorAddButton, new TransistorAddWindow());
        detailsWindowsPairs.Add(ZenerDiodeAddButton, new ZenerDiodeAddWindow());
    }

private void AddDetailButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           detailsWindowsPairs.GetValueOrDefault((CustomButton)sender).Show();
    }
```

Функционал кнопки подразумевает любое количество открытий и закрытий окна. Однако, после первого закрытия окна, при попытке вызвать его повторно, вылетает исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как его обойти?

Comment: Так окно надо просто создавать заново `new MyWindow()` и после этого делать `Show()`.

Comment: @aepot как это сделать, если у меня Show() вызывается динамически на любом окне в словаре& То есть, как создать объект типа, которого не заешь?

Comment: Например так `Dictionary<CustomButton, Func<Window>>` `.Add(ZenerDiodeAddButton, () => new ZenerDiodeAddWindow());` `.GetValueOrDefault((CustomButton)sender)?.Invoke().Show();`